# Kubernetes: How can I set a minimum lifetime of a job / pod?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-jobs

On my master node I am running **Kubernetes v1.16.3** which users will submit some jobs to our servers from time to time, which is working right now. However, in my case I have many users and they should not only have priorites on their jobs, but also a ***minimum* lifetime** of each job / pod.

The ***minimum*** lifetime should guarantee that a job will run at least for example 5 hours. If our resources are fully used and a user submits a job with a higher priority than the current running jobs, then only those running jobs that have exceeded the minimum lifetime should be candidates to be evicted.

I am not able to find a solution for this. I only can find a *maximum* lifetime solution (https://medium.com/@ptagr/give-your-kubernetes-pods-a-lifetime-8c039d622faf) , which represents the duration of the lifetime on which the job / pod will be evicted after the provided time has expired. But that's not what I want. I would like to create a job / pod that is protected for 5 hours to be run and after the specified time has elapsed the job / pod ***should still be running***, but when another new job comes by (that has for example a minimum lifetime of 3 hours) the old running job / pod should be evicted and the newly created job / pod should take its place and run for at least 3 hours before of being a candidate of getting killed by another job.

Is this even possible to achieve this in Kubernetes? Or is there a workaround on achieving that?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes' scheduler doesn't understand time so not directly. You can set PriorityClasses and PodDisruptionBudgets (in this case the budget being maxDisruptions 0) which control voluntary evictions. It might be possible to write something which changes the PriorityClass value after a certain amount of time but I don't know anything off-the-shelf for that, would be a custom operator.